# How to check type of struct's field in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, typechecking

Let's say I have:

```
defmodule Operator do

    defstruct operator: nil 

    @type t :: %Operator {
        operator: oper
    }

    @type oper :: logic | arithmetic | nil
    @type logic :: :or | :and
    @type arithmetic :: :add | :mul 

end
```

then I can:

```
o = %Operator{operator: :and}
```

Is it to possible to check whether `o.operator` is `logic`, `arithmetic` or `nil` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typespecs in Elixir are annotations, you can't really interact with them from your code without repeating part of them. Therefore, you can write:

```
def operator(%Operator{operator: op}) when op in [:or, :and, :add, :mul, nil] do
  ...
end
```

Or alternatively:

```
@ops [:or, :and, :add, :mul, nil]

def operator(%Operator{operator: op}) when op in @ops do
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank You. I will think about some macro to do it.